# Canonical basis of cycles of Riemann surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $\Gamma$ be the compact Riemann surface defiend by the algebraic curve
$$
f(x, y) = y^n + a_1(x)y^{n-1} + a_2(x) y^{n-2} + \dots + a_{n-1}(x)y + a_n(x) = 0,
$$
where $a_1(x), \dots, a_n(x)$ are polynomials of $x$.
I want to perform integration on $\Gamma$, especially the integration of Abelian differentials along the canonical cycles (a basis for the homology of $\Gamma$).
However,I don't know how to choose a canonical basis of cycles for numerical calculations.

In B. Deconinck and M. van Hoeij's article (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0167-2789(01)00156-7), they construct the canonical cycles by using the Tretkoff–Tretkoff algorithm. They also developed a Maple package "algcurves" contains the implementation of this algorithm.

Consider the ellptic curve $y^2 = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. By using the command `homology`, we can obtain the following result.
[image: homology]
The `canonicalcycles` contains the canonical cycles $a_1$ and $b_1$.
As described in their article [p. 38], `a_1 = [[1, [1., 1], 2, [2., -1]]]` is read as: “From
sheet 1 proceed to sheet 2, by encircling the branch point x = 1. (countclockwise), then from sheet 2 proceed to sheet 1, by encircling the branch point x=2. (clockwise)”.
Here is what confuses me, since I don't understand how it became a cycle, and how to ensure that the intersect number of $a_1$ and $b_1$ is $1$. Can someone give me some guidance?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I will try to contact the author, thank you.